# Can 2 vectors in dimensions greater than 3 be found on a plane?

Tags: vectors, mathematics, geometry, linear-algebra

I was thinking about how, given any 2 linearly independent vectors in a 3D cartesian coordinate system, one can always find another 3D cartesian coordinate system (or should I say frame) where the 2 vectors only lie on a plane (spanning across 2 axes). Could the same be said for a 4D cartesian coordinate system (or even greater dimensions)? How would you prove it?

(If possible, appeal to physical understanding)

Comment: It's hard to appeal to physical understanding here, as very few, or perhaps no one, can visualize four dimensional spaces.

Comment: Alright then, any other answer would suffice. Or maybe an answer that utilizes more physically intuitive facts about dimensions/axes. (e.g. all axes are perpendicular to each other)

Comment: Perpendicular axes isn't a physical phenomenon -- it's just a choice that Descartes made that makes the math easy in cases where there's not other obvious symmetries (like cylindrical or spherical).

Comment: Dot products and cross products are still a thing in higher dimensions. And the cross product will still give a vector perpendicular to your given 2 vectors, thus defining a n-dimensional plane that contains those 2 vectors.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

This is a long-standing result from [linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra).  If you have $m$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional real space $\mathbb R^n$, with $n > m$, then those vectors can form a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) for a real space $\mathbb R^{p \le m}$.

If the set of $m$ vectors are all linearly independent, then they will span a space in $\mathbb R^m$.

In your case, say you have the vector $\mathbf a = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots\end{bmatrix}$ and the vector $\mathbf b = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & 0 & \cdots\end{bmatrix}$.  These vectors are orthogonal (i.e., they lie at right angles to one another in their space), and they define a plane -- i.e., a space in $\mathbb R^2$.

To make my example easy I chose to zero out the tail end of each vector -- but all you need is for the two vectors to be [linearly independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence).  So  $\mathbf a = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots\end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf b = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots\end{bmatrix}$ also works to form a basis.

One last caveat: I mentioned that $m$ vectors form a basis for a space in $\mathbb R^{p \le m}$.  The reason for this is that a set of $m$ vectors may not span an $m$-dimensional space.  Without getting too deep into the linear algebra, if the set of $m$ vectors can be assembled into a matrix of rank $p$, then they make a basis for a space in $\mathbb R^p$.  But if there are linear dependencies between the vectors, then $p < m$ will be true -- you can only get $p = m$ when the vectors are all mutually linearly independent.

Answer (score 3):

Given two non-zero vectors $\vec{A}$, $\vec{B}$, define an orthonormal set of basis vectors as follows:

- For the first basis vector, define $\hat{e}_1$ to point in the direction of $\vec{A}$.
- For the second basis vector, define $\hat{e}_2$ to point in the direction of $$\vec{B}_\perp = \vec{B} - \frac{\vec{B}\cdot \vec{A}}{\vec{A}\cdot \vec{A}}\vec{A}.$$  Intuitively, $\vec{B}_\perp$ is the projection of $\vec{B}$ orthogonal to $\vec{A}$, and it will be non-zero so long as $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ are not parallel.  Note that by construction, both $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ can be written as a linear combination of $\hat{e}_1$ and $\hat{e}_2$.
- For the remaining vectors $\{\hat{e}_3, \hat{e}_4, \dots \hat{e}_n \}$, choose an orthonormal basis for the space of vectors orthogonal to both $\hat{e}_1$ and $\hat{e}_2$.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your question almost asks precisely for what is defined as a [Hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane)

As you probably know, a $\text{2D}$ plane embedded in a $\text{3D}$ Euclidean space can be parameterized by:

$$ ax+by+cz+d=0 $$

The real parameters $a,b,c$ are immediately seen to be a vector normal to the plane, since taking any two points $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$,$(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ that lie within the plane, and hence satisfy the above equation, we can form a vector $\mathbf{v}=(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1,z_2-z_1)$ and from a simple subtraction of equations we obtain

$$ a(x_2-x_1)+b(y_2-y_1)+c(z_2-z_1) = 0 $$
(Note that $d$ cancels out when we do this).

Now to address your question, starting with $2$ linearly independent vectors $\bf{v}$,$\bf{u}$ in $\text{3D}$ space, you can find a third vector normal to both: $\hat{n}=(a,b,c)$ by demanding it is perpendicular to both:

$$ av_x+bv_y+cv_z = 0 $$
$$ au_x+bu_y+cu_z = 0 $$

Since you have some freedom of normalization of $\hat{n}=(a,b,c)$ you can also add the requirement that $\hat{n}$ is a unit vector:

$$ a^2+b^2+c^2=1 $$
or alternatively replace the $1$ with any other numerical constant you like.

Thus, the triad of vectors $\mathbf{v}$,$\mathbf{u}$,$\hat{n}$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{E}^3$.

Note that $\mathbb{E}^3$ and $\mathbb{E}^7$ have the additional nice peculiarity that one can obtain $\hat{n}$ immediately by the cross product: $$ \hat{n} = \frac{\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{u}}{\lvert\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{u}\rvert} $$

(Although, [you can](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Multilinear_algebra) generalize the cross product to $\mathbb{E}^n$ of any dimension $n$ at the cost of it becoming a non-binary operation).

But even without a cross product, the same idea immediately extends to any Euclidean space of dimension $n$ (aka $\mathbb{E}^n$). Starting with $n-1$ linearly independent vectors denoted $\mathbf{v}^{(i)}$ one can solve for the hyperplane normal $\hat{n} = (a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n)$ by solving the $n$ equations system:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_iv_{i}^{(1)}} = 0, \sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_iv_{i}^{(2)}} = 0, \dots , \sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_iv_{i}^{(n-1)}} = 0 , \sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i^2} = 1 $$